# Why does TextInput not work on my Xiaomi device in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Poco X3 Pro to be exact. For some reason I'm unable to use any TextInput on my device. It works on my other Samsung phone and works in emulator as well, but on my phone the keyboard is not responding at all, I'm able to focus into the input, but I can't press the keyboard.

expo version: ~45.0.0
react native version: 0.68.2

Comment: Please add code snippet to reproduce the error.

Comment: Code was not at fault. It was some kind of issue with the Expo app. Fixed after reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the Expo app solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the "display over other apps" option for open the performance monitor. Turn off the "display over other apps" option for Expo Go App